# Cannot update maven2 repository in IntelliJ - low disk space

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I setup a new Spring Boot project by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye3dfrrEPCg). I used the Spring Initializer to make a new Gradle Project. I get the following message upon launching the project:

> Unindexed remote maven repositories found. The following repositories
> used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet:
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 If you want to use dependency
> completion for these repositories artifacts, Open Repositories List,
> select required repositories and press "Update" button

When I open the repo list, I see the following:

[image: Repository List]

As you can see, it gives the following error when I try to update the repo:

> java.io.ioexception there is not enough space on the disk to update maven

Some more information: IntelliJ is installed onto my D:\ drive which has 39.6GB free. My C:\ drive only has 2GB free. I've tried changing where the `User Settings file` and `Local repository` are located, but it doesn't seem to help:

[image: Maven setup]

Is there some other setting I should be changing so that it can download the repository successfully? This is really annoying because when I try to make a .jar file by running `gradlew build`, my build errors out saying:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration':testCompileClasspath'.
>
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Comment: Just to be sure, make more available space on disk C:\ (try up to 10Gb)

Comment: @arsen_adzhiametov I'm trying to make it so I don't need to use the C:\ at all.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. I'm just saing that your TEMP directory still on C:\ and probably it used as temporatily storage during downloading.

Comment: I managed to free up 8.5 GB and it was able to download successfully. Is there anyway to make the TEMP directory not on C:? Also I'm still getting the junit error. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Actually I was able to fix the junit directory error by removing the Test directory from my project.